# Assertion `IsArray()' failed (RapidJSON)

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I was testing the RapidJSON library earlier today to see if I could parse a document with nested values, and for some reason I couldn't come up with a solution to the errors I was getting. I searched around Google and Stack Overflow for an hour or two and couldn't find a fix. Here is the code along with the errors:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

#include "include.hpp"

int main() {
    unsigned int input = 1;
    tile output;
    output = LoadTile("../locations.json", input);

    std::cout << output.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

load.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/filereadstream.h"

#include "include.hpp"

using namespace rapidjson;

tile LoadTile(std::string fileName, unsigned int number) {
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");

    char buffer[2048];
    FileReadStream stream(file, buffer, 2048);

    Document doc;
    doc.ParseStream(stream);

    tile output;
    Value& tileNumber = doc[number];

    if(!tileNumber.IsObject()) {
        output.overflow = true;
        output.x = 0;
        output.y = 0;
        output.type = "\0";
    }else{
        output.x = tileNumber[0]["x"].GetInt();
        output.y = tileNumber[0]["y"].GetInt();
        output.type = tileNumber[0]["type"].GetString();
    }

    return output;
}
```

include.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

struct tile {
int x;
int y;
std::string type;
bool overflow = false;
};

tile LoadTile(std::string fileName, unsigned int number);
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(test)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "test")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} main.cpp load.cpp include.hpp)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin})
```

locations.json:

```
{
    1:[
        {"x":32},
        {"y":32},
        {"type":"water_c"}
    ]
}
```

Errors:

```
test: /home/.../rapidjson/document.h:1547:rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::operator[](rapidjson::SizeType) [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::SizeType = unsigned int]: Assertion `IsArray()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I know it's not the JSON formatting, I've tried everything. Unless there's something *really* wrong with it. I'm running this on Xubuntu 16.10. Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. In JSON, keys must be strings, written with double quotes. More details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp). 
I suggest using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON strings.
The valid JSON looks like this (1 in double quotes):

```
{
    "1": [{
        "x": 32
    }, {
        "y": 32
    }, {
        "type": "water_c"
    }]
}
```